# How to change State variables one after another in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-state, swiftui-menu

I have a `Menu` with a few buttons. Each button represents an URL.
On selecting one of the buttons I want to present a webView loading the said URL using `.fullScreenCover(isPresented:)`

```
@State private var showWebPage = false
@State private var urlToLoad = ""

// ...

View()
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Menu {
                Button("FAQ", action: {
                    presentWebView(for: "https://example.com/faqsLink")
                })
                Button("Privacy Policy", action: {
                    presentWebView(for: "https://example.com/privacyLink")
                })
                Button("Terms and Conditions", action: {
                    presentWebView(for: "https://example.com/termsLink")
                })
            }
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWebPage) {
        WebView(url: URL(string: urlToLoad)!)
    }

private func presentWebView(for url: String) {
    urlToLoad = url
    showWebPage.toggle()
}
```

Everytime I try this, `urlToLoad` is still empty when I toggle `showWebPage`
I feel it has to do with how `@State` works but can't figure it out, I'm still new to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the hint from Delano I managed to come up with this:

```
 .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWebPage) {
                    WebView(url: URL(string: urlToLoad)!)
                        .withCloseButton(and: "FAQ")
                }
                .onChange(of: urlToLoad) { value in
                    log.info (value)
                    if !value.isEmpty {
                        showWebPage.toggle()
                    }
                }
```

and in the  button action I just update the value of `urlToLoad`

Hope this helps out somebody, I spent more time on this than I ever thought a Menu needed.